# Always gives false even though file exists and is not empty

Tags: bash

I have a bash script:

```
echo " enter file name "
read $file
if [ -f "$file" ] && [ -s "$file" ]
then 
   echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
else
   echo " file exists and is not empty "
fi
```

No matter what I enter as a `$file`, it gives me the false value. I can even enter a file that does not even exist; it still will give me the false value. Why is that?

Comment: You need a space after the `&&`

Comment: It was my editing mistake, I fixed it. But this solution does not work.

Comment: And the `-f` tests for the file existing, but you've got it in the "does not exist" portion

Comment: what do you think `[ -f "$file" ] && [ -s "$file" ]` does?

Comment: Does your `$file` variable contains full path to file?

Comment: If you used `set -x` when running this, or `bash -x yourscript`, you would see it running `[ -f '' ]` and `[ -s '' ]`, which would have given you a clue before asking here that `file` wasn't being correctly set (due to the `$` in `read $file`).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

It is enough to check for `-s`, because it says:

> FILE exists and has a size greater than zero

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test

also your output is switched, so it outputs `does not exists` when a file exists, because `-s` will give `TRUE` if file exists AND has a `size > 0`.

So correctly you should use:

```
echo " enter file name "
read file
if [ -s "$file" ]
then 
   echo " file exists and is not empty "
else
   echo " file does not exist, or is empty "
fi
```

This will give you the expected output.

Also it should be

```
read file
```

instead of

```
read $file
```

If you want further informations, I recommand reading [`man test`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) and [`man read`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)

Comment: -s returns true incase of `dir`. If we want to only check for none empty files then combine -f and -s condition

Answer (score 11):

Please note, that `[ -f "$file" ] && [ -s "$file" ]` will return `true` if file exists and is not empty.

Other option:

```
if [[ -f "/path/to/file" && -s "/path/to/file" ]]; then 
    echo "exist and not empty"
else 
    echo "not exist or empty"; 
fi
```

Comment: Another option `[ -f "$file" -a -s "$file" ]`

Comment: Shellcheck actually warns against this : ```Prefer [ p ] && [ q ] as [ p -a q ] is not well defined.```

Answer (score 1):

This is the true solution:

```
if [[ -f $file && -s $file ]]
```

With `[[` the quotes are unnecessary because `[[` handles empty strings and strings with whitespace more intuitively.

The solution that was proposed to you:

```
if [ -s "$file" ]
```

is wrong because it is instead equivalent to:

```
if [[ -e $file && -s $file ]]
```

which, in addition to the regular files dictated by the word `-f`, also looks for:

1. Directory
2. Symbolic Link
3. Block Special Device
4. Character Device
5. Unix Socket (local domain socket)
6. Named Pipe

Comment: `[` is shell, `[[` is bash (shell is the minimal terminal interpretor, bash is an advanced interpretor)

Comment: In fact the question is tagged `bash`.